# mac terminal: Adding 127.0.0.1 calypso.localhost to localhost file

Tags: macos, terminal, wp-calypso

I am trying out wp-calypso which requires an addition to my localhost file. Via the terminal, I first typed

```
sudo vim /etc/localhost
```

which took me here

```
...                                                                                                                                           

~                                                                                                                                            

~                                                                                                                                            

~                                                                                                                                            

~                                                                                                                                            

~                                                                                                                                            

"/etc/localhost" [New File]
```

I seem to be presented with a different screen than what's presented in the guide via https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/

I then in the first line tried typing..

```
172.0.0.1      calypso.localhost                                                                                                                                          

~                                                                                                                                            

~                                                                                                                                            

~                                                                                                                                            

~                                                                                                                                            

~                                                                                                                                            

-- INSERT --
```

and realized I had no idea what to do next. Am I even in the right file? What would be my next steps?

Comment: Try looking at /etc/hosts instead. I think that might be the file you're looking for

Comment: whoops, that makes sense. It seems going to this page, even when using sudo, doesn't let me edit?

Comment: Are you using vim, are you familiar with how vim works? If not, try sudo nano /etc/hosts. If you are trying to save with vim, are you getting an error?

Comment: nano worked much better for me, and my server is up and running. thanks!

Comment: Posted the contents of my comments as an answer. Have a good one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a mac, the file you are looking for is `/etc/hosts`, not `/etc/localhost`.

Using nano:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

Enter your sudo password, then navigate your cursor to the end of the file and add the line for calypso:

```
127.0.0.1    calypso.localhost
```

Hit `ctrl-x` then `y` to save your hosts file.